# Syntax for setting a var in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I haven't used C++ in a while, and I'm trying to re-familiarize myself with it.  I was trying to work through a tutorial that had this bit of code in it:

```
int x {2};
```

to set a variable.  It's not part of a struct, class or union or anything like that.  They're just using that syntax to set x to 2.  Except that I can't get it to compile.  I'm using VS2010 and even downloading their examples won't let me compile with that syntax.  I this somehow managed code?  It was billed as a console project though, and I fear I'm missing something very simple.

Thanks

Comment: [Why not ?](http://ideone.com/4JaLGe), just use C++11

Comment: Braces also get rid of Most Vexing Parse (mostly). Consider `T f(U())` vs `T f{U{}}`

Comment: Because VS2010 is what I --  and my employer -- work with.  I used to code in C++ a while ago, and I'm just trying to bring myself back up to speed.

Comment: Check the C++11 support list of MSVC10 to be aware of what modern features you could use (Its linked in my answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int x{0}`

The braces are another way to call ctors since C++11, a feature called ["Uniform initialization"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Uniform_initialization).

Note that feature [is not implemented by MSVC10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), thats why it doesn't work in Visual Studio 2010.